# How to delete the comment in the pdf?

Tags: pdf

I've tried using Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat to delete a comment in a pdf file. The comment was restored the moment I deleted it. How to delete it?
File: https://github.com/mjs225/deletepdf/raw/main/HowToDelete.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to try your example, because it was using a non-standard font that would have required me to download a font pack.

In general, to delete a comment in Adobe Reader, you simply right-click on the comment you want to delete, and select "Delete" in the menu that pops up.

[image: Right-click and select Delete]

Comments never come back when I delete them that way. If your comments continue to return, then it sounds like there's something wrong with your document.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the file with a common font Times New Roman at the same url. (It's weird that although I can edit the comment, I can't delete it)

Comment: I'm running Acrobat Reader DC version 2020.012.20048 for Windows. If I right-click the comment in your updated example and select "Delete", it deletes the comment. Make sure you SAVE THE PDF again after you deleted the comment. Once I do that and open the PDF again in Acrobat Reader, the comment is no longer there.